# When using the project navigator using the keyboard how to open a file in the secondary pane?

Tags: xcode, xcode13

Pressing `CMD+1` changes focus to the project navigator!

Once you have focus, using the arrow keys allows you to scroll through all the files in the navigator and automatically opening it in the focused pane.

How does one open a file in the secondary pane, using only the keyboard, when one had focus of the file in the project navigator ?

Answer (score 0):

First use CMD+J to gain focus of the pane where you want the file to open.

Then do CMD+1 to get to the project navigator and move to the file you want -> it will automatically open the file in the focused window.